# UITableView touch position or several gestures at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, touch, gesture

I have UITableView, and added the ability for moving cells.

http://s017.radikal.ru/i402/1503/76/3442a9517cec.png

So, if longPressGesture is recognized, i make the cell hidden, take a snapshot of cell(on picture highlighted with grey), and change it's position while longPressGestureStateChanged. But the animation of moving looks bad.

If I add panGesture while longPressGestureBegan, it doesn't work until I touch up and touch down again, and after that panGestureStateChanged begin working, and moving become smooth.

I need panGesture begin working while longPressGestureBegan, or catch the screen touch position.

But the difficulty is: (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event; etc... doesn't work on UITableView.

I read a lot, but nothing was founded. This is the custom case. I need for example to recognize pinchGesture only when longPressGesture was recognized, without touching up.

Anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For `UITableView` use ready methods to move cells. You can find more information in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1).

Comment: I need to move cell while tableViewEditingStyle = NO. That's the reason I try to do this. Also I have a custon cell with custom swipes, so modifying the style of table view in editable mode doesn't suit me